# Login and Pay with Amazon - aspnet mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

What happen if i want to remove login step(**amazon customer account**) but they can still pay to my amazon account(**seller account**).
I mean customer can pay to seller account by enter theirs credit or master card to my form(on my eCommerce website) then money can transfer straight to my amazon account(seller account). Because some customer dont have amazon buyer account (or even they dont want to creat new one). 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To use Amazon payments, your customers **must** have (or create a new) Amazon account.

> **What is Amazon Payments?**
>
> Amazon Payments is a service that provides you with the **ability to use
>   the payment methods already associated with your Amazon.com account** to
>   make payments for goods or services on third-party websites. To make a
>   payment, you can use any of the payment methods on file in your
>   Amazon.com account.

https://payments.amazon.com/help/201754640

When you use "3rd party" payment services (e.g. Amazon, Paypal Standard) you are effectively outsourcing payment (gateway) processing to them.

If you want to handle payment processing on your own (re - *"enter credit card info on my form"*), you have to obtain your own (bank) internet Merchant account and meet [PCI compliance](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/) requirements.

You can also look into services like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/).

Hth.